# Removing/Disabling Firewall on Linux CentOs seem to happen temporarily

Tags: linux, firewall, centos, iptables

I tried following the instructions in [this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-howto-disable-remove-firewall/) to disable and remove iptables firewall using commands:

```
# service iptables save
# service iptables stop
# chkconfig iptables off
# iptables -F
# iptables -X
# iptables -t nat -F
# iptables -t nat -X
# iptables -t mangle -F
# iptables -t mangle -X
# iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
# iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Its seems to work temporarily and then the firewall gets enabled again by itself even without restarting.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There might be other background processes that automatically regenerate the iptables ruleset.

You must understand that iptables is just a userland program to manipulate the `netfilter` tables *in the kernel*. It *can't* be 'turned off', except by recompiling the kernel. The command `service iptables stop` actually just issues a 'flush' directive against the in-kernel tables.

If any other process invokes the `iptables` program (or manipulate the in-kernel netfilter tables directly via `libnetfilter`) then the ruleset will be repopulated.

So, if you want to prevent the netfilter ruleset from being regenerated, you must audit your running processes. `fail2ban`, for instance, automagically generates netfilter rules.